# How to get a specific JTree node given a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, jtree

If I have a `String[]` such as `{ "root", "two", "1" }` how can I get the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` from my `JTree` that is represented by this "path"?

For example if my JTree looks like this:

```
root
 one
  1
  2
 two
  1   <-- I want this node
  2
```

Assume all nodes are `DefaultMutableTreeNode`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to fetch the tree model with `getModel()` method. Once you have the model, it has the `getRoot()` method, to fetch the root of the tree. After that, you can follow with calls to `getChild(Object parent, int index)` and check if any of the children has the same name as the one provided in the String array. If you find such one, you can again call `getChild(Object parent, int index)`, etc... until you arrive at the last String from the array. Then you have the corresponding tree node. You need to actually cast the tree nodes to DefaultMutableTreeNode, as the TreeModel uses Object as the tree elements (for pre-1.7 Java).